# Problems after the installation of Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning

I personally wanted to change from Windows 10 to Ubuntu because it was more smooth and because I code a lot.

I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.4 from the original site and I decided to install it on my notebook. It is a HP that had Windows 8.1 installed. Ubuntu was installed perfectly, and there wasn't any error. So I decided to install it on my PC. **My PC is an Acer Aspire GX-281**.

But when I rebooted my PC, Ubuntu wasn't there. There was only Windows Boot Manager.

So, I uninstalled Ubuntu from the installation program, and reinstalled it again. But **nothing**, *nothing*. I decided to get back in Windows and I got into the Windows 10 installation program. The partition where I've installed Ubuntu 2 times was empty. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you follow a guide on installing with dual partitions? If yes can you link it to your answer? That way we can rule out simple things.

Comment: What does "*I uninstalled Ubuntu from the installation program*" mean? There is no 'uninstall Ubuntu' option or application in the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: Please provide a link to whatever instructions you followed.

Comment: Um, i didn't follow a guide. I tried installing it on my notebook and it worked. I tried making a swap partition. But nothing.